# R parsing large data frame - speed optimization

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have an extremely large data frame with 2 columns and .5 mil rows.
For example, a few rows may look like this:

```
# Start    End
# 89       100
# 93       120
# 95       125
# 101      NA
# 115      NA
# 123      NA
# 124      NA
```

I would like to manipulate this data frame to output a data frame that looks
like this:

```
# End     Start
# 100     89, 93, 95
# 120     101, 115
# 125     123, 124
```

What would be the absolute quickest way to do this, given that there are
.5 million rows? bgoldst suggested this awesome piece of code:

```
# m is a large two column data frame
end <- na.omit(m[,'V2']);
out <- data.frame(End=end,
Start=unname(sapply(split(m[,'V1'],findInterval(m[,'V1'],end [as.character(0:c(length(end)-1))],paste,collapse='.')))
```

However this is taking a little bit too long.

Thanks for the help!

The answers on the possible duplicate post did not address the time issue. bgoldst's answer produced the desired outcome, but was very slow on my computer. I was wondering if there was something further that I could do to make this run faster.

Comment: The answers on the possible duplicate post did not address the time issue.

Comment: Consider to use something like C/C++ instead.

Comment: Is this `end <- na.omit(m[,'V2']);` slow as well?

Comment: No it takes barely any time, 0 seconds

Comment: @Chani Reposting an identical question is not the appropriate way to attract attention to a question on SO.

Comment: @Chani I've added an answer to the duplicate question. Try if it is fast enough for your needs and if it gives the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with data.table may be faster:

```
library(data.table)
dt = setDT(df)[, id:=findInterval(Start, End[!is.na(End)])][,paste(Start,collapse=','),id]

result = data.frame(End = df$End[!is.na(df$End)],Start = dt$V1)
#  End    Start
#1 100 89,93,95
#2 120  101,115
#3 125      123
```

Comment: The time this took was about the same as a data.frame unfortunately